# 3 young girls and 2 adult girls are getting invited by 3 boys to dance. find the 2 dimensional probabilities table

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, proof-verification

I got stucked a little with calculating the probabilities table for the following question:

There're $5$ girls - $2$ adult and $3$ young girls. $3$ boys invite randomly $3$ girls to a dance (without return). If a young girl is invited to dance, there's a probability of $0.9$ she accepts the invite. If an adult girl is invited to dance, there's a probability of $0.5$ she accepts the invite.

Let's mark:

- $X=$ number of girls dancing
- $Y=$ number of adult girls received an invite

So below is what I did and I'm missing what I did wrong with the calculations. Probably my mistakes are at $Y=1, Y=2$ columns *(all the cells won't sum up to 1)*.

[image]

Would appreciate your guidance and advice